# Uploading to Google Drive from Command Line on Mac

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use a cron job to upload a file from my local disk into Google Drive but so far, I can't figure out how to do it.  I'm on a Mac, but I am well versed in the Linux command line though I'm not very skilled at all in scripting.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I felt I should add here, I've been using the [free CLI application called "duck" (a command line version of CyberDuck for the Mac)](https://duck.sh/) to do these uploads on my linux and mac boxes.  It is free.

This works very well, though on the Mac it does have some minor annoyances with access, if you use it in a script of some kind launched by Lauchd in the background, when upgrading it often wants to be re-authorized to use the login keychain.  If this happens, run the script manually from the command line and then the appropriate dialogs will come up to ask for permission.  On the Mac, the OAuth credentials are stored in the keychain.

Answer (score 2):

I hope by now you have figured out...If that is not the case, try [skicka](https://github.com/google/skicka) or [gdrive](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) or [GoogleCL](https://code.google.com/p/googlecl/) (this last is available for installation via homebrew too).

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it by just moving the file to upload to a local folder that is synchronized with Google Drive. It works for me but you need to be logged in into your Google account.

Answer (score 0):

worth mentioning it looks like GoogleCL is not (no longer) supporting Drive.  I found no mention on the landing page or the wiki.

Comment: This is probably best placed as a comment on the accepted answer, since it directly relates to that answer. This space should be reserved for new answers that attempt to fully answer the question.